# Animated CAShapeLayer Pie

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation, core-graphics

I am trying to create a simple and animated pie chart using `CAShapeLayer`. I want it to animate from 0 to a provided percentage.

To create the shape layer I use:

```
CGMutablePathRef piePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(piePath, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(piePath, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2, 0);
CGPathAddArc(piePath, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2, radius, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90), DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90), 0);        
CGPathAddLineToPoint(piePath, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2 + radius * cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90)), self.frame.size.height/2 + radius * sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90)));

pie = [CAShapeLayer layer];
pie.fillColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
pie.path = piePath;

[self.layer addSublayer:pie];
```

Then to animate I use:

```
CGMutablePathRef newPiePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddLineToPoint(newPiePath, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2, 0);    
CGPathMoveToPoint(newPiePath, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
CGPathAddArc(newPiePath, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2, radius, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90), DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(125), 0);                
CGPathAddLineToPoint(newPiePath, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2 + radius * cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(125)), self.frame.size.height/2 + radius * sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(125)));    

CABasicAnimation *pieAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
pieAnimation.duration = 1.0;
pieAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
pieAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pieAnimation.fromValue = pie.path;
pieAnimation.toValue = newPiePath;

[pie addAnimation:pieAnimation forKey:@"animatePath"];
```

Obviously, this is animating in a really odd way. The shape just kind of grows into its final state. Is there an easy way to make this animation follow the direction of the circle? Or is that a limitation of `CAShapeLayer` animations?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might be interested in this: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I know this question has long been answered, but I don't quite think this is a good case for `CAShapeLayer` and `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Core Animation has the power to do animation tweening for us. Here's a class (with a wrapping `UIView`, if you like) that I use to accomplish the effect pretty well.

The layer subclass enables implicit animation for the progress property, but the view class wraps its setter in a `UIView` animation method. The interesting (and ultimately useful) side effect of using a 0.0 length animation with `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` is that each animation cancels out the previous one, leading to a smooth, fast, high-framerate pie, like [this](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/333W150F2U2u1E302d1x/Animated.mov) (animated) and [this](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/162T2x1h0b1k460I1446/Not%20Animated.mov) (not animated, but incremented).

`DZRoundProgressView.h`

```
@interface DZRoundProgressLayer : CALayer

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat progress;

@end

@interface DZRoundProgressView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat progress;

@end
```

`DZRoundProgressView.m`

```
#import "DZRoundProgressView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation DZRoundProgressLayer

// Using Core Animation's generated properties allows
// it to do tweening for us.
@dynamic progress;

// This is the core of what does animation for us. It
// tells CoreAnimation that it needs to redisplay on
// each new value of progress, including tweened ones.
+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [key isEqualToString:@"progress"] || [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}

// This is the other crucial half to tweening.
// The animation we return is compatible with that
// used by UIView, but it also enables implicit
// filling-up-the-pie animations.
- (id)actionForKey:(NSString *) aKey {
    if ([aKey isEqualToString:@"progress"]) {
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:aKey];
        animation.fromValue = [self.presentationLayer valueForKey:aKey];
        return animation;
    }
    return [super actionForKey:aKey];
}

// This is the gold; the drawing of the pie itself.
// In this code, it draws in a "HUD"-y style, using
// the same color to fill as the border.
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 1, 1);

    CGColorRef borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    CGColorRef backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithWhite: 1.0 alpha: 0.15] CGColor];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, backgroundColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, borderColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);

    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);

    CGFloat radius = MIN(CGRectGetMidX(circleRect), CGRectGetMidY(circleRect));
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(radius, CGRectGetMidY(circleRect));
    CGFloat startAngle = -M_PI / 2;
    CGFloat endAngle = self.progress * 2 * M_PI + startAngle;
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, borderColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    [super drawInContext:context];
}

@end

@implementation DZRoundProgressView
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [DZRoundProgressLayer class];
}

- (id)init {
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 37.0f, 37.0f)];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
        [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress {
    [(id)self.layer setProgress:progress];
}

- (CGFloat)progress {
    return [(id)self.layer progress];
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm not getting the animation to work. could you attach a link to a sample code. (GIT hub..or something else)

Comment: Sorry about that! I've updated the code, and future updates are available [in an open source piece code of mine](https://github.com/zwaldowski/DZProgressController/blob/master/DZProgressController.m).

Comment: Wait, WHY is this better than CAShapeLayer? Wouldn't CAShapeLayer be a lot faster?

Comment: CAShapeLayer might be ever-so-slightly faster, but not by much if you were to use it in this same way (redrawing on frame and progress change), with the addition that with CAShapeLayer animation between paths wouldn't work. CAShapeLayer's default tweened animation is a "morph" rather than a "grow", and if you were to do it yourself using a keyframe animation, it'd be equally expensive and all on the CPU. This isn't the fastest way to do it, but it's still reasonably fast because we're not drawing shadows or anything.

Comment: +1 excellent. Could you please extend the code such that it allows also reverse animations as process decreases. I'm currently facing problems with applying `clearColor` to sectors.

Comment: I have posted a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603558/animated-pie-chart-that-can-animate-in-both-directions)

Comment: I would like to have this pie animation embedded in a video "AVExportSession". Therefore the animation duration should be the time defining the progress from 0 ... 1. I am not able to figure out how to do that. If I set .fromValue = 0 and .toValue = 1 the pie is already fully filled at the beginning of the animation.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you make a keyframe animation instead:

```
pie.bounds = CGRectMake(-0.5 * radius,
                        -0.5 * radius,
                        radius,
                        radius);

NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < nrSteps + 1; i++)
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointZero];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(radius * cosf(startAngle),
                                     radius * sinf(startAngle))];
    [path addArcWithCenter:...
                  endAngle:startAngle + i * (endAngle - startAngle) / nrSteps
                           ...];
    [path closePath];
    [values addObject:(__bridge id)path.CGPath];
}
```

Basic animation is good for scalars/vectors. But do you want it to interpolate your paths?

Answer (score 2):

Quick copy/paste Swift translation of [this excellent Objective-C answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9150991/3128245).

```
class ProgressView: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        genericInit()
    }

    private func genericInit() {
        self.opaque = false;
        self.layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        self.layer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    var progress : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            (self.layer as! ProgressLayer).progress = progress
        }
    }

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return ProgressLayer.self
    }

    func updateWith(progress : CGFloat) {
        self.progress = progress
    }
}

class ProgressLayer: CALayer {

    @NSManaged var progress : CGFloat

    override class func needsDisplayForKey(key: String!) -> Bool{

        return key == "progress" || super.needsDisplayForKey(key);
    }

    override func actionForKey(event: String!) -> CAAction! {

        if event == "progress" {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: event)
            animation.duration = 0.2
            animation.fromValue = self.presentationLayer().valueForKey(event)
            return animation
        }

        return super.actionForKey(event)
    }

    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext!) {

        if progress != 0 {

            let circleRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 1, 1)
            let borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            let backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, backgroundColor)
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, borderColor)
            CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2)

            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect)
            CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect)

            let radius = min(CGRectGetMidX(circleRect), CGRectGetMidY(circleRect))
            let center = CGPointMake(radius, CGRectGetMidY(circleRect))
            let startAngle = CGFloat(-(M_PI/2))
            let endAngle = CGFloat(startAngle + 2 * CGFloat(M_PI * Double(progress)))

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, borderColor)
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, center.x, center.y)
            CGContextAddArc(ctx, center.x, center.y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, 0)
            CGContextClosePath(ctx)
            CGContextFillPath(ctx)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3

```
class ProgressView: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        genericInit()
    }

    private func genericInit() {
        self.isOpaque = false;
        self.layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        self.layer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    var progress : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            (self.layer as! ProgressLayer).progress = progress
        }
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return ProgressLayer.self
    }

    func updateWith(progress : CGFloat) {
        self.progress = progress
    }
}

class ProgressLayer: CALayer {

    @NSManaged var progress : CGFloat

    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool{

        return key == "progress" || super.needsDisplay(forKey: key);
    }

    override func action(forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {

        if event == "progress" {

            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: event)
            animation.duration = 0.2
            animation.fromValue = self.presentation()?.value(forKey: event) ?? 0
            return animation

        }

        return super.action(forKey: event)
    }

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {

        if progress != 0 {

            let circleRect = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 1, dy: 1)
            let borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            let backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

            ctx.setFillColor(backgroundColor)
            ctx.setStrokeColor(borderColor)
            ctx.setLineWidth(2)

            ctx.fillEllipse(in: circleRect)
            ctx.strokeEllipse(in: circleRect)

            let radius = min(circleRect.midX, circleRect.midY)
            let center = CGPoint(x: radius, y: circleRect.midY)
            let startAngle = CGFloat(-(Double.pi/2))
            let endAngle = CGFloat(startAngle + 2 * CGFloat(Double.pi * Double(progress)))

            ctx.setFillColor(borderColor)
            ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x:center.x , y: center.y))
            ctx.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:center.x, y: center.y), radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            ctx.closePath()
            ctx.fillPath()
        }
    }
}
```